# Why isn't my desktop powering off with "systemctl poweroff"?

Tags: debian, shutdown

Why isn't my desktop powering off with `systemctl poweroff`?

What I did:

```
sudo -s
systemctl poweroff
```

got

```
"reboot: system halted"
```

System: armbian (debian-10-buster on orangepiplus2e) 32-bit

Comment: Could you explain more detail about what exactly did you do and what exactly happened?

Comment: What happens if you do `shutdown -h now` (it may be the same, it is what I do)?

Comment: I amended you question to add your amendment, form your comment. You can also edit your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You have not said what hardware.

If a Raspberry Pi, then it does not have the hardware to turn off the power. It will do everything else, but can not remove the power (unless you add a power supply that can receive the message, and add the software to send it, and integrate it into the power-off software).

Comment: This looks like it's the case. http://www.orangepi.org/orangepiplus2e/ shows the Orange Pi +2E as having what looks like a simple DC input connector for power, with no native ability to communicate with the external power supply as would pretty much be required to implement software-controlled power-off. So the problem isn't that the OS isn't using that feature; it's almost certainly that it's not even there.

Comment: Not the case, it is the board. It also has a power button, so I would not rule out that it has software control. However there is a strong possibility that it does not.

Comment: I meant "This looks like it's the case" as in "It looks like this is the correct answer".

Answer (score 1):

This is generally due to a buggy BIOS or issues with drivers.

You might try one of these :

- updating your BIOS
- updating your graphic card driver
- disabling IRQs in the ACPI configuration (acpi=noirq)
- fully disabling ACPI in the BIOS

Comment: I don't have a bios. Thanks.

Comment: A return to say adding **acpi=noirq** in Linux kernel options works in my case on an old computer **Dell Dimension E521** which does not have the **ACPI** option available in its BIOS. This option make both correct a blocking "IO-APIC kernel panic" and permits the complete poweroff of the system. To make permanent : **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT** in **/etc/default/grub** and **update-grub** after and reboot to load this option before the system's loading (tested with a **Debian 11** system).